# SharePoint: How to combine Filter from Business data list with External List

Tags: sharepoint, bcs

SharePoint External List Web Part allows users to edit/view/delete an item in the list, and the Business data list web part has a filter to allow users to search an external list but the results are read-only. I would like to know to program or create an extendable filter like the one in the Business data to search the external list and results are shown as the Editable external list.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this blog post. It is pretty close to what you are trying to achieve.

http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/

Comment: Good to see my Blog post being posted as a answer! Yes its first time for me :D